# How to get a button hidden when [disabled]="true"

Tags: angular, ionic2

Button is getting disabled, but I wanted it to hide from UI if the disabled condition is true -

```
<button ion-button block 
    class="button-color-blue"
    [disabled]="true" 
    (click)="closePage()">
    Cancel
</button>
```

Comment: Use ng-hide directive with a conditioned based scope value ..as `ng-hide="isDisabled"` or `ng-if='isDisabled'`

Comment: I wanted completely hidden widget on condition, and I used [hidden] instead of [disabled], now working fine. Thanks for quick suggestion to all

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with something like :

```
// NOT RENDERED AL ALL
<button ion-button block class="button-color-blue" *ngIf="condition===false" [disabled]="true" (click)="closePage()">Cancel</button

// HIDE ONLY
<button ion-button block class="button-color-blue" [style.display-none]="true" [disabled]="true" (click)="closePage()">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, it was my mistake, instead of disabled I used hidden

so,

instead of this -

```
<button ion-button block class="button-color-blue" [disabled]="true" (click)="closePage()">Cancel</button>
```

use this if you wanted invisible of item

```
  <button ion-button block class="button-color-blue" [hidden]="true" (click)="closePage()">Cancel</button>
```